# How to increase the "check" range for a radiobutton

Tags: css

I am trying to make it possible for the user to check a radiobutton while clicking on its parent's div.

Here is the code:

```
        <td style="width: 17.5%">
            <input
                type="radio"
                :id="item.subValue"
                :name="item.fieldname"
            /><label :for="item.subValue">{{ item.subValue }}</label>
        </td>
```

As you can see, I am using a td, how can I make it that clicking on the td will let you check the radiobutton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
  <label :for="item.subValue">
    <input
       type="radio"
       :id="item.subValue"
       :name="item.fieldname"> {{ item.subValue }}
  </label>
</td>
```

If you want `label` to be full width of container add CSS `display: block;` to it

Comment: If the `<input>` is within the `<label>`, then the `for` attribute of the `<label>` becomes optional.